# MySQL query timesout

Tags: mysql, select, timeout

I have two tables, a message table and a log table.

I want to return all rows in the message table that have been logged to a user and whose message # is greater than a passed parameter.

What I have is:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE id IN ( SELECT msg_id AS id FROM msg_log WHERE user_num='1000' AND msg_id >='1660192')
```

This query returns nothing, produces no errors, it simply times out... It doesn't matter if it run from a PHP script or phpMyAdmin. In fact, if run from phpMyAdmin it doesn't even show the query is running, but it doesn't allow you to execute another query.

If I break out the `IN` select

```
SELECT msg_id AS id FROM msg_log WHERE user_num='1000' AND msg_id >='1660192')
```

This returns 0 records (as it should)

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT message.* FROM message 
INNER JOIN msg_log 
    ON message.id = msg_log.msg_id
   AND msg_log.user_num = '1000' 
   AND msg_logmsg_id >= '1660192'
```

The `INNER JOIN` syntax should be faster than `IN` clause.
Naturally you could speed query up having

- *message.id* as `INDEX` or `PRIMARY_KEY`
- msg_log.id as `INDEX` and probably related to *message.id* with a `FOREIGN_KEY`

Comment: Thanks Marco... don't know why I didn't think to do an inner join, I think I just got hung up on the timeout issue.

Comment: @ppetree: sometimes we get lost on "easy" things making then every moment more difficult to solve... and when we're given the solution we say "it was so easy, how could I miss it?". I think everyone here had a similar experience, so don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing this query from mysql monitor without php? You may have large tables and mysql need to more time to execute the query than php script is allowed to take. You may try:

1) add index on user_num in msg_log table which may speed the query,

2) set `php_max_execution_time` in `.htaccess` to allow php to execute longer scripts

Comment: Thanks Zefiryn, it wasn't timeing out because of the table size as the test platform has fairly small tables.  It just didn't like that query for some reason.  Marco gave me a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Inner join is faster than IN due to a peculiarity of MySQL.  What MySQL does is run the subquery *for every row it encounters*.  This is unusual behavior for a database, but it is documented.

A join fixes this problem.  However, the right equivalent syntax requires a distinct:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m join
     (select distinct msg_id
      from msg_log
      WHERE user_num='1000' AND msg_id >='1660192'
     ) ml
     on ml.msg_id = m.id
```

The distinct is important, if you want to avoid having multiple rows for each message.

You can also fix it with the EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM message m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM msg_log ml
              WHERE user_num='1000' AND msg_id >='1660192' and m.id = ml.msg_id
             )
```

If you have a preference for correlated subqueries over joins.